# Change Camera.app Settings manually with iFile?

Tags: iphone, ios, camera, jailbreak

I repaired my phone and the connector to the front camera broked. So I tried to open the Camera.app and detected that I can't switch back to the Rear Camera, because the Camera.app freezes because of the broken Front Camera.

When I open my own Application, which makes the Photos with the Front Camera it works.

I've my phone jailbreaked and iFile installed. Is there a way to change these settings manually on the file system? Where can I change that?

PS: I don't want to make a Settings Reset, because then I've all Data cleared, and the camera works so long as I switch the camera again to the front camer, then the app freezes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it:

In the Plist `/System/Library/CoreServices/SpringBoard.app/N90AP.plist`

I set the Value
`front-facing-camera` to `false`

and after reboot it worked.